# How to build a Java 8 stream from System.in / System.console()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a file, we can transform it into a stream of strings using, e.g.,

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"))
```

Can we build a stream of lines from the standard input in a similar way?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611661/how-to-make-scanner-strings-into-a-stream-in-java

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A compilation of kocko's answer and Holger's comment:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Stream<String> stream = in.lines().limit(numberOfLinesToBeRead);
```

Comment: Should probably be wrapped in a try-with-finally block.

Answer (score 4):

you can use just `Scanner` in combination with `Stream::generate`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> input = Stream.generate(in::next)
                           .limit(numberOfLinesToBeRead)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or (to avoid `NoSuchElementException` if user terminates before limit is reached):

```
Iterable<String> it = () -> new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> input = StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false)
            .limit(numberOfLinesToBeRead)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the stream ends before the limit (e.g. with Ctrl/Cmd+D).

Comment: @AjahnCharles fixed

Answer (score 1):

Usually the standard input is read line by line, so what you can do is store all the read line into a collection, and then create a `Stream` that operates on it.

For example:

```
List<String> allReadLines = new ArrayList<String>();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && s.length() != 0) {
    allReadLines.add(s);
}

Stream<String> stream = allReadLines.stream();
```

Comment: If you have a `BufferedReader` there is no need for storing the lines into a `Collection` to [get a `Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--). The bigger problem is that interactive consoles usually don’t have an end-of-file…

Comment: Nice one. Didn't know this newly introduces method. Thanks, @Holger. :)

Comment: Great, BufferedReader.lines will eliminate much of the verbosity in this answer. If the numer of lines to be read is known, then in.limit(numberOfLines) should work here

Comment: _"interactive consoles usually don’t have an end-of-file…"_ Don't you get an end-of-file when the program terminates? :-P

Comment: @Lii: no, a terminated program will not receive an end-of-file as a terminated program can’t receive anything.