# How to make scanner strings into a Stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In `Java8`, how can I form a `Stream` of `String` out of the scanner read results?

```
InputStream is = A.class.getResourceAsStream("data.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(is), "UTF-8");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

That is turn a scanner into a stream which I would like to iterate using `forEach`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It is impossible to have a stream of strings in the way you want.

Comment: @Radiodef how exactly?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `Scanner implements Iterator`. So the answer is the same. (Make a `Spliterator` and use `StreamSupport`.)

Comment: @Radiodef clever. You are correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong, no `Scanner` is required:

```
try (final InputStream is = A.class.getResourceAsStream("data.txt");
        final Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
        final Stream<String> lines = br.lines()) {

}
```

If you really want to use a `Scanner` then it `implements Iterator` so you can just do:

```
public Stream<String> streamScanner(final Scanner scanner) {
    final Spliterator<String> splt = Spliterators.spliterator(scanner, Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL);
    return StreamSupport.stream(splt, false)
            .onClose(scanner::close);
}
```

P.S. you also don't seem to be closing resources. **always** close an `InputStream`.

Comment: Is `lines` instantiated in a lazy way or `br.lines` reads all the lines?

Comment: @StephanRozinsky it's a `Stream`. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is similar to answer with `Files.lines` below and the entire file can be read only if I use `forEach` on it. I'm learning these things so not confident yet.

Comment: @StephanRozinsky correct. In Java 8 every `Stream` is lazy.

Comment: Is the declaration of each object separately (InputStream, Reader, BufferedReader) to ensure try-with-resources cleans up each?

Comment: @AjahnCharles nope. Just for clarity because `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(A.class.getResourceAsStream("data.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).br.lines()` just isn't very readable. `close()` is required to close dependant resources.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a `Scanner` at all. Just the the resource as a `URL`.

```
URL url = A.class.getResource("data.txt");
Files.lines(Paths.get(url.getPath())).forEach(line -> {});
```

Comment: If it's on the class path this won't work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh yeah, I guess it won't work if it's a JAR.

Comment: Am I right that `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(...))` reads entire file while Files.lines establishes a stream such the without iterating it I will not read the entire file - so lazyness will work ?

Comment: @StephanRozinsky According to documentation, yes.

Comment: `Files.lines` uses a `BufferedReader`, so it doesn't read the actual file line-by-line.