# Java getResource not working in a .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, getresource

i am trying to export a pacman game i made from eclipse to a .jar package. The problem is that while everything runs fine on eclipse, when the .jar is exported, the resources i use dont load properly. I have them in a separate [/res folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJwdb.jpg), which is on the build path. I access them in the following ways:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    try{
         image = ImageIO.read(new File(classLoader.getResource("images/PM0.gif").getFile()));
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
```

`File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("levels/"+fileName).getFile());`

What am i doing wrong?[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s5ZQ.png) is an example of the errors i get(only in the exported .jar on eclipse it runs fine)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access resources in JAR file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393194/how-to-access-resources-in-jar-file)

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and you can't use `File` to access them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with resources, you should always have them as streams and not as files (unless you're trying to do something really weird).

try the following:

```
ImageIO.read(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("images/PM0.gif"))
```

Comment: I tried it seems to work, but a scanner i am using is giving me problems `Scanner s = new Scanner(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("levels/"+fileName)); `  This doesnt seem to work properly when packaged.

Comment: @user19955 If you're trying to read the file than you should not be using Scanner, try that solution instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611661/how-to-make-scanner-strings-into-a-stream-in-java

Answer (score 3):

In order to retrieve resources from placed inside a jar, you need to use `getResourceAsStream()`.

It works on eclipse because the runtime environment is executed using the "unpacked" JAR  ( or better put - prepacked ) using actual files.