# How to accommodate System.out.println() in Functional Programming in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, side-effects, pure-function

I want to ask the user for inputs using System.out.println(). Like, System.out.println("Enter name"). But, that would produce side-effects. Is there any way to bypass that?

```
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String customerName = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter contact no: ");
        String contactNo = sc.next();
        accounts = (List<Account>) UserService.CreateAccount
                .apply(accounts, new Account(accounts.size() + 1, customerName, contactNo)).get();
        System.out.println("Created account with Number " + accounts.size() + "\n\n");
```

Comment: your question is unclear to me

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow.com! Unfortunately, it's unclear what you are asking. Why do you want to avoid side effects (you can't)? Are you asking about how to handle side effects in functional programming? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan - Displaying output could be considered a side effect. In FP, functions are (largely) meant to be pure, meaning they have no side effects.

Comment: The other question does not give solutions to my question. @sleske

Comment: Then, how can I ask for inputs? Is there an FP approach for that?

Comment: @awesomemypro, consuming external input is *also* a side effect.  A pure function cannot do it.  You have to allow yourself some deviation from pure FP if you want your program to interact with its environment, and in particular, if you want it to perform I/O.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154405/how-to-build-a-java-8-stream-from-system-in-system-console