# Taking multiple lines with multiple inputs in each Lines

Tags: java, java-8

My requirement is to take multiple inputs from user on multiple lines.

Each line signifies inputs with meanings of : `Power Energy Idea Strength` each separated by just one space.

Input:

```
2 4 5 7
3 4 8 1 
4 2 3 6
```

Output consists of List:

```
List<Integer> power = {2,3,4}
List<Integer> energy = {4,4,2}
List<Integer> idea = {5,8,3}
List<Integer> strength = {7,1,6}
```

**preferred solution is in Java, but if Java-8 solutions can be given i would love it.**

i have tried so far as below but no luck:

```
        String input = "";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;
        while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
            line = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            input += line + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(input);
```

i am able to read input in multiple lines but not able to save them as separate category in `List`.

Comment: `String::split` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply split the line and put the value in separate lists:

```
    line = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    String arr[] = line.split(" ");// spiting the line based on space
    if (arr.length==4) { // check if length is 4 as you are expecting
    // use Integer.valueOf() to convert from string to Integer
        power.add(arr[0]);
        energy.add(arr[1]);
        idea.add(arr[2]);
        strength.add(arr[3]);
    }else {
        //throw exception or break
    }
    input += line + "\n";
}
```

Regarding how to use java 8 stream API in System.in check [How to build a Java 8 stream from System.in / System.console()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154405/how-to-build-a-java-8-stream-from-system-in-system-console)

Comment: You would add a String to an Integer List, you need to use Integer.valueOf to get the Integer value

Comment: @ILikeSahne as per comments in the code `// use Integer.valuesOf() to convert into Integer`

Comment: @ScaryWombat quiet complicated, considering the `Scanner` has already a `nextInt()` method which can read the next int number within the current line…

Answer (score 0):

U can input as much values as u want with this program:

```
List<Integer> power = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> energy = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> idea = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> strength = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
  String s = sc.nextLine();
  if(s.equals("exit")) break;
  String args = s.split(" ");
  if(args.length >= 4) {
    power.add(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));
    energy.add(Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
    idea.add(Integer.valueOf(args[2]));
    strength.add(Integer.valueOf(args[3]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a typo, u need to use Integer.valueOf instead of Integer.valuesOf

Comment: why are you always using `args[0]` ?

Comment: my bad forgot to change

Comment: why change from the OP's `while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {` ?

Comment: Wouldn't you then never get out of the while loop?

Comment: ohh mb i first accidentaly used `power[i]` thats why i did it so, of course while is better my bad

Comment: @ILikeSahne to break out of the `while (keyboard.hasNextLine())` is very easy